# Cloud DNS Usage statistic

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I'm newbie in this service and use trial account.

About one week ago I have move one of my sites DNS to Google Cloud DNS.
Everything works fine but I cant understand "usage statistic" in API because it's counter does not increase.

For example, this site has a small amount of visitors (about 700 daily) and I thought that I should see theirs requests to DNS and this requests should be counted.
But I still see in statistic only this [(screenshot)](http://puu.sh/fk06P/04faa6089b.png).
There is only 27 requests that has been made by me when I configured records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage statistics are for API calls (the ones you make to configure your zone). DNS queries are not currently reported, though your billing statement will give you an aggregate count.

Comment: @Sergey If the answer is helpful, please mark it as 'correct' by clicking the green checkbox.

Comment: Is this still the case or have they added a way to view your query usage? I'm curious how my TTL values are going to affect my bill. Thanks